# Design pattern about file uploading list and service/activity

Tags: android, service, upload, queue

1. I have a ListActivity to let user pick photo(s) to be upload
2. For upload, I'll put photos inside a static ArrayList called PhotoList
3. After that, I'll start a Service to upload those photos
4. Now, user may switch to another activity to do some other things
5. Later, user will back to this ListActivity to check upload status. Also in here they can pick more photos to be upload.

So, my PhotoList is actually a kind of Queue, but it also a data to be display at ListActivity.

My problem is, when the Service is running, and user picked more photo(s), I would like put those photo(s) inside the PhotoList.
(I don't want to start Service again since the service is already running...)

Now I just get stuck here.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm testing about IntentService and something...Need few more day to implement that after your suggestion.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okey I will try to give you a solution based on my understanding to your problem : 
You have a list with photos and you want the user to be eligible to upload those images and update it the user of it status ( uploaded/ uploading / upload/failed) and you dont want to start the `Service` every time you upload .

a Simple working solution is to use an [`IntnetService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) i will be running only if there is tasks assigned to it and will atomically shut down when finish the work and of course the job will be in a sperate thread when working with `IntentService`

```
step 1
```

make a database table contains data about the images

```
_id integer 
_image_uri 
_image_status :
```

`_image_status` will hold one of these values ( 1-uploaded : finish_uploaded , 2- uploading: service is uploading the image , 3-upload : the user can upload the image 4-failed: failed to upload you can retry )

```
step2
```

now in the `UploadIntentService` try to upload the image to server and when if the upload competes successfully or an error happened while upload update the database

```
public class UploadIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = UploadIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int STATUS_UPLOAD = 0x01; //can be uploaded
    public static final int STATUS_FAILED_TO_UPLOAD = 0x02; // tried to upload but failed
    public static final int STATUS_UPLOADING = 0x03; // self explanied
    public static final int STATUS_SUCCESSFULLY_UPLOADED = 0x04; // the image uploaded to server 

    public UploadIntentService() {
        super(TAG);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        int status = intent.getIntExtra("status", -1);
        String imageUri = intent.getStringExtra("image_path");
        long imageDatabaseid = intent.getLongExtra("image_db_address",-1);

        if(status != STATUS_SUCCESSFULLY_UPLOADED && status != STATUS_UPLOADING){

            try{
                //update _image_status column with value of STATUS_UPLOADING with the image_id = imageDatabaseid;

                //upload code 

                //successfully uploaded 
                //update _image_status column with value of STATUS_SUCCESSFULLY_UPLOADED with the image_id = imageDatabaseid;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                //update _image_status column with value of STATUS_FAILED_TO_UPLOAD with the image_id = imageDatabaseid;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

......

```
step3
```

and you `ListActivity` if you want to upload any image use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, UploadIntentService.class);
    Bundle uploadExtras = new Bundle(3);
    uploadExtras.putLong("image_db_address", PUT HERE THE IMAGE DATABASE ID );
    uploadExtras.putInt("status", PUT HERE THE IMAGE STATUS );
    uploadExtras.putString("image_path", PUT HERE THE IMAGE PATH IN FILE SYSTEM);

    intent.putExtras(uploadExtras);
    context.startService(intent);
```

.......
    step 4

make sure you declare the Service in the manifest.xml , and enjoy.

Comment: it is no the best solution though :) you can enhance it more

Answer (score 1):

You can make a [`BlockingQueue`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) in which you will store photos to upload. This `BlockingQueue` is your `PhotoList`. In `Service`, in loop, you will look into this `BlockingQueue`. Two cases are possible:

1. There is some photo. Take it and upload.
2. Queue is empty. So the thread will go to sleep, `BlockingQueue` assures this.

Answer (score 1):

Your Service should override the onResume() function. onResume() is called whenever the user does other tasks, opens other activities etc and finally returns back to your application's activity. That is just the gist.

You can learn more about [Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) . The concepts that apply for Activity apply for Service also, in that Service is just not "shown" to the user.

In the above link, you will learn when an activity is recreated, and when it is actually resumed by calling onResume(). You also need to override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` so as to pass state objects between your old Activity instance and the new one.

What you can do is, when the user goes leaves your activity, in your `onSaveInstanceState()`, you should save your state variables eg. your list of selected photos, in a Bundle. And pass this Bundle to `onRestoreInstanceState()`

**Question:** Are you actually starting your service as a valid [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) ? I mean, are you extending the Service class? I've used Service for my projects, and they always resumed where they left without overriding anything. **The reason:** Services run in background, resources are not released until the service is done doing it's job. So if you have not used Service , then I recommend you do that. Your problems will be taken care of.

Comment: Yes I did extend Service class. I'm working on a new project right now, your message did help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

[Copy On Write Array List](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

This will be a **thread-safe random-access list**.

Check this link for good explanation and example.

[Difference between ArrayList and CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://techvivek.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/difference-between-arraylist-and-copyonwritearraylist/)

`Iterators` of this list never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. When an `iterator` is created, it keeps a copy of the list's contents. **It is always safe to iterate this list**.